# Using Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE in API below 26

Tags: android, memory-management, android-support-library, android-bitmap, android-8.0-oreo

There is a new `Bitmap.Config` type in `Android API 26` (Oreo), called `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE`. It allows storing a Bitmap in the **graphic card's memory** only, instead of the heap.

As I'm storing a lot of `Bitmap`s in my app, this seems like a super useful feature, as it can help avoiding `OutOfMemoryError`s. The problem is, I'd like to support devices all the way back to Ice Cream Sandwich, so my `minSdkVersion` is `14`.

Is there a way I could use this on devices below `API 26`?

I know **Support Libraries** was made to solve this problem, but I've never used it before, and it seems to be broken up into smaller units (each offering backwards compatibility for a specific problem), and I can't seem to find anything related to `Bitmap.Config` [in this list](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html).

Is there any chance a support library will be published later that provides backward compatibility for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I could use this on devices below API 26?

No, sorry.

> Is there any chance a support library will be published later that provides backward compatibility for this functionality?

It is very, very unlikely.